# Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch

[root@3-6-17-40 ~]# sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@3-6-17-40 ~]# curl -X GET "localhost:9200/"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Error Screenshot
[image]

To Fix This, edit /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
```

Press i for insert text then move to bottom,

add below code in end of the page

*ES_TMPDIR=/var/log/elasticsearch*

To Save File, Click ESC then type :wq to save and exit.

Start Elastic search now

```
systemctl start elasticsearch
```

To Verify it's services running

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
```

To Confirm Elasticsearch running

```
curl localhost:9200
```

Comment: For future posts, please consider the following guidelines - details of the problem should reside in the initial post/ question and not in additional answers. Also, this is not a Magento specific problem, it's an ES issue.